# Average jagged array by index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of arrays that looks like: `var data = [[2, 2,3], [3, 9], [5, 6,7,8]];`
([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/h6FzN/))
I need to be able to create a new array based on each inner array's index. So from the above output I'm looking for

```
1 - [2,3,5]
2 - [2,9,6]
3 - [3,7]
4 - [8]
```

helper average method:

```
Array.prototype.average = function () {
        var sum = this.sum();
        return sum / this.length;
    };
```

I've got something like :

```
var data = [[2, 2,3], [3, 9], [5, 6,7,8]];
    //Sconsole.log(data);

    Array.prototype.averageAll = function () {
        var avgArrays = [[]];
        var self = this;

        for (var i = 0; i < self.length; i++) {
            avgArrays[0].push(self[i][0]);
        }
        return avgArrays[0].average();
    };
    //3.333 to the console
    console.log(data.averageAll());
```

I've hardcoded in the season here because if I try to use `avgArrays[i][i]` I get an error `push is not defined`.  For my simple example, the function calculates the average of the 0th position of each array in the array. If I have arrays of varying sizes like this, how can I make this go slickly in one fell swoop?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is the intended output a number representing the average of everything?

Comment: @AndreiNemes look at the four arrays I'm looking for above.  The function should return an array this is the average of each of those.

Comment: With `[[2, 2, 3], [3, 9], [5, 6, 7, 8]]` it should return `[2.33, 6, 6.5]`?

Comment: @Andreas I'm looking to take the first index of each array and create a new array with that.  Then take the second index of each array and make a new array with that.  I then want to return an array of those array's averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.sum = function () {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        total += this[i];
    }
    return total;
};
Array.prototype.average = function () {
    var sum = this.sum();
    return sum / this.length;
};
 var data = [[2, 2,3], [3, 9], [5, 6,7,8]];
//Sconsole.log(data);

Array.prototype.averageAll = function () {
    var avgArrays = [];
    var self = this;
    //in an array of arrays, val is an array
    var maxLen = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < self.length; i++) {
        if(self[i].length > maxLen)            
        {
            maxLen = self[i].length;
        }
    }
    console.log('maxlen is ' + maxLen);
    for(var j = 0; j < maxLen; j++) {
        avgArrays.push([]);
        for(var k = 0; k < self.length; k++) {
            if(self[k][j]){
                   avgArrays[j].push(self[k][j]);
                }
        }
    }
    console.log(avgArrays);
    var result = []
    for (var x = 0; x < avgArrays.length; x++) {
        result.push(avgArrays[x].average());
    }
    return result;
};

console.log(data.averageAll());
```

Answer (score 2):

reduce can be handy here-

```
var data= [[2, 2, 3], [3, 9], [5, 6, 7, 8]];

data.Average= function(itm){
    return data.Sum(itm)/(itm.length);
}

data.Sum= function(itm){
    return itm.reduce(function(a, b){
        return a+b
    });
}
data.map(data.Average);

/*  returned value: (Array)
2.3333333333333335,6,6.5
*/
```

A comment reminded me to add a 'shim' for IE8 and lower- the other browsers get map and reduce-

```
(function(){
    var ap= Array.prototype; //IE8 & lower
    if(!ap.map){
        ap.map= function(fun, scope){
            var T= this, L= T.length, A= Array(L), i= 0;
            if(typeof fun== 'function'){
                while(i<L){
                    if(i in T){
                        A[i]= fun.call(scope, T[i], i, T);
                    }
                    ++i;
                }
                return A;
            }
        };
    }
    if(!ap.reduce){
        ap.reduce= function(fun, temp, scope){
            var T= this, i= 0, len= T.length, temp;
            if(typeof fun=== 'function'){
                if(temp== undefined) temp= T[i++];
                while(i<len){
                    if(i in T) temp= fun.call(scope, temp, T[i], i, T);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            return temp;
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Is reduce a new-ish addition to JavaScript?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Yes, [ECMA5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) standard addition

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code should construct your array for you:

```
var data = [[2, 2,3], [3, 9], [5, 6,7,8]];
var max = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    max = data[i].length > max ? data[i].length : max
}

var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    result[i] = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        if(i < data[j].length) {
            result[i].push(data[j][i]);
        }    
    }
}
```

After that, it is trivial to calculate the average:

```
var averages = [];
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var array = result[i];

    var sum = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        sum += array[j];
    }

    averages.push(sum / array.length);
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9sr4j/1/).

Answer (score 1):

So if I understood correctly, you want a new array made up of averages of your sub arrays?
Here is a simple way to do it, by leveraging *built-in* array functions

```
var data = [[2, 2,3], [3, 9], [5, 6,7,8]];

var averageAll = function(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(a) {
    return a.reduce(function(b,c) { return b+c; })/a.length;
  });
};

averageAll(data);
// -> [2.3333333333333335, 6, 6.5]
```

Also, as a rule of thumb, don't mess with the standard types' prototypes, in my experience it only leads to trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
    [2, 2, 3],
    [3, 9],
    [5, 6, 7, 8]
];

Array.prototype.averageAll = function() {
    var result = [],
        maxIdx = Math.max.apply(Math, this.map(function(arr) { return arr.length }));

    for (var i = 0; i < maxIdx; i++) {
        var sum = this.reduce(function(old, cur) {
            return old + (cur[i] || 0);
        }, 0);

        result.push(sum / this.length);
    }

    return result;
};

console.log(data.averageAll());
//[3.3333333333333335, 5.666666666666667, 3.3333333333333335, 2.6666666666666665]
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4cw6/)